# Tool to Peek into WCF SOAP message

Tags: wcf, soap

I know there is a tool that enables me to see what actually gets sent/received in my WCF application, that is it let's me see the actual SOAP messages being passed down the wire.
The problem is I don't remember what that tool was called, and my Google skills are not of much help either. Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your looking for the Service Trace Viewier.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

Comment: I don't see the soap messages.

Comment: Me too. It seems that Trace Viewer shows only service messaging, but not client ones.

Answer (score 5):

[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) works, so long as you're using HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Wireskark](http://www.wireshark.org/), it will capture just about everything.

Answer (score 1):

some info here

[XML From a Web Service Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205546/xml-from-a-web-service-call)

Answer (score 1):

Use WCFTestClient.

Answer (score 0):

I enable tracing for the service and use Microsoft Service Trace Viewer to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a WCF expert but I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for all the HTTP sniffing sorts of tasks